Egger's test and funnel plot for multi-level meta-analytic data
I'm using metafor (rma.mv) and clubSandwich to run an Egger's test in order to check for publication bias for my multi-level meta-analysis. I could find very little online on how to modify a Egger's test for multi-level meta data and subsequently transform the results into a funnel plot, so I am a bit in doubt whether my code makes sense/if am I doing the right thing. Anyone experience with running an Egger's in a multi-level meta-analysis and can briefly check if my code makes sense? Many thanks in advance!
I worked with the following modified code:
egger_multi <- rma.mv(Effectsize, Effectsize_Va^2, random = ~ 1 |
    Study_Id / Effectsize_Id, mods = ~ Effectsize_Va, data = Data_DSMIV)

coef_test(egger_multi, vcov = "CR2")

#create a funnel plot with the results of the Egger's test.

library(metafor)

dat <- Data_DSMIV
res <- rma.mv(Effectsize, Effectsize_Va, random = ~ 1 | Study_Id/Effectsize_Id, data=dat)
res
funnel(res)

cols <- palette.colors(length(unique(dat$Study_Id)), palette="Alphabet")
cols <- cols[as.numeric(factor(dat$Study_Id))]
funnel(res, col=cols)


Does Effectsize_Va contain the standard errors or the sampling variances of the effect sizes? The second argument of the rma.mv() function is for the sampling variances (or an entire variance-covariance matrix), so if Effectsize_Va actually contains the variances (Va sounds like variance), then you should not be squaring them. Also, for egger_multi you square Effectsize_Va but not for res so this is inconsistent. Assuming that Effectsize_Va really contains the variances, then the code should be:
egger_multi <- rma.mv(Effectsize, Effectsize_Va, random = ~ 1 |
    Study_Id / Effectsize_Id, mods = ~ sqrt(Effectsize_Va), data = Data_DSMIV)

And to actually show the results of Egger's test in the funnel plot, you could then use:
se <- seq(0, max(sqrt(Data_DSMIV$Effectsize_Va)), length=100)
lines(coef(egger_multi)[1] + coef(egger_multi)[2]*se, se, lwd=3)

